# Emacs Linum-mode no fringe in Cocoa

Tags: emacs

I have the issue visualized here:

[image: My emacs]

The problem is the fringe is not colouring the background of my linum line numbers. I'm using Emacs 24.3.1 with Solarized color theme.

I've looked over various threads, which claims to fix this issue. However, I couldn't get any of them to work.

Any clues?

Comment: Are you using `color-theme-solarized` or the new way of doing emacs color themes for emacs24?

Comment: I've installed it using package-install and the marmalade repo.
And added ``(load-theme 'solarized-dark t)`` to my .emacs file

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "the fringe is not colouring the background of my linum line numbers".

Comment: Line numbers are shown in the *display margin*, not in the fringe.  While these look the same, they are not.  The fringe face is not applied to display margins by default, so you need to configure linum faces independently.

Answer (score 1):

Try `M-x customize-face linum` and then `Show All Attributes`. Change the value of the `Background` variable and it should change. Easier than having to edit the actual theme file.

Answer (score 1):

```
(set-face-attribute 'fringe nil :background "white" :foreground "white")
```

Set the fringe color to whatever you want.

Comment: He's saying that the fringe color is not being applied to the linum numbers because they have a different font face.